# How to get facebook friends list using facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a demo for facebook friend list,And goen through facebook api [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/friendlist),

I have implemeted as per suggested in the facebook api docs,But i only got friends count from it,Can any buddy please tell me how to get fiernds name and profile pic from facebook api,my code is as belo:

**code**

```
new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/friends", null,
                HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */

                        System.out
                                .println("=============my frineds============"
                                        + response);
                    }

                }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since v2.0 you can only get friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons. More information can be found in the answer over here: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)